# Android Bitmap from URL always null

Tags: java, android, image, bitmap, bitmapfactory

I'm trying to download an image from a URL and convert it into a bitmap, but the line

```
Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
```

always causes the debugger to skip to the following line

```
return null;
```

without ever actually printing out the stack trace and the Exception variable also doesn't exist in the variables listed in the Debugger.  I read a lot about how there might be issues with urls not actually leading to images, not well formated images and the like but it still has the same issue with a hardcoded image that I'm positive exists.

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(
                "http://www.helpinghomelesscats.com/images/cat1.jpg");
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                .openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        return myBitmap;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Since it seems like the manifest.xml file might be involved I've edited to add here.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.delivery"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".IntroPage"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Browse"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".ViewProduct"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".ViewOrder"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".GetAddress"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".ConfirmOrder"></activity>
</application>
```

Comment: have you used internet permission?

Comment: please try to see what've been throwed, you can log the IOexception using Log.i("TAG",e.getMessage) and post it here

Comment: If the debugger skips to the `return null;` in your `catch` branch, there _must_ have been an exception thrown and the variable `e` should contain that exception.

Comment: Yes, internet permission is there.  That's what's so concerning to me, even when I add the Log.i("TAG",e.getMessage), and put breakpoints on that line and the e.printStackTrace() line it still doesn't stop until the return null line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

following code work for all type of images.

```
    try {

        URL url = new URL("http://www.helpinghomelesscats.com/images/cat1.jpg");
        InputStream in = url.openConnection().getInputStream(); 
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(in,1024*8);
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        int len=0;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        while((len = bis.read(buffer)) != -1){
            out.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }
        out.close();
        bis.close();

        byte[] data = out.toByteArray();
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for coding a reliable answer that doesn't pipe the InputStream into the BitmapFactory. Though I would suggest re-indenting your code as it doesn't look very nice.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you may give these 2 pemssions in the android manifeast file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
```

In your activity:

```
url="http://www.helpinghomelesscats.com/images/cat1.jpg"
Bitmap bmp=readBitmapFromNetwork(url);



 public static Bitmap readBitmapFromNetwork(String imgurl) {
         URL url;
         Bitmap bmp = null;
         InputStream is = null;
           BufferedInputStream bis = null;
           System.out.println("image url ==========   "+imgurl);
        try {

            url=new URL(imgurl);
            System.out.println("url.getPath()"+url.getPath());          
                try {
               URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
                    conn.connect();
                    is = conn.getInputStream();
                    bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {                 
                    System.out.println("Bad ad URL");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {                   
                    System.out.println("Could not get remote ad image");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

        } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
         finally {
                try {
                    if( is != null )
                        is.close();
                    if( bis != null )
                      bis.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("Error closing stream.");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }   


           return bmp;
            }
```

Comment: This code catches an exception on the `conn.connect();` line and then prints out the following error.

Comment: 11-21 10:34:34.554: W/System.err(818): java.net.UnknownHostException: Host is unresolved: www.helpinghomelesscats.com:80

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, found it on here while searching out another issue.  This way it's not holding up the UI.  works very well in ArrayAdapters as well.

Useage:

```
_coverArt = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.top_CoverArt);

new DownloadImageTask(_coverArt)
            .execute("Put your URL here Hint: make sure it's valid http://www.blah...");
```

The Asynctask

```
class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
ImageView bmImage;

public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
    this.bmImage = bmImage;
}

protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
    String urldisplay = urls[0];
    Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
    try {
        InputStream in = new URL(urldisplay).openStream();
        mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return mIcon11;
}

protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
    bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
}
}
```